# Determine the type of operation that called DDL trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, ddl

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbchanges 
(
    ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(),
    operationType VARCHAR(16),
    [Date] DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

I need my DDL trigger to register all changes happening in database in that table. Is it possible to determine the type of operation that called the trigger (CREATE, DROP, etc)?

I'm using Transact-SQL.

Comment: See [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/165283/81026).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, using the [`EVENTDATA()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-eventdata-function?view=sql-server-2017) built in function. This function returns an XML value that contains information about the event that fired the DDL trigger such as the time of the event, the event type, and so on.

You can use this function inside a DDL trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbchanges_ddl
ON <database name here>
FOR DDL_TABLE_EVENTS -- alter, create and drop table
AS 

DECLARE @data XML,
        @EventType nvarchar(100);
SET @data = EVENTDATA();

SET @EventType = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)');

/* 
    Currently, we can examin the content of @EventType to know if 
    the statement that fired the trigger is an alter, create or a drop statement,
    However we have no information about what TABLE is mensioned in that statement.

    To get that information, we need to parse the actual SQL statement.
    We get the statement using TSQLCommand:
*/

DECLARE @Statement nvarchar(4000);
SET @Statement = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand)[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)');

-- Now you can check if the command refers to the table you want to monitor or not,
-- by looking for the name of the table inside the statement.


IF @statement LIKE '%dbchanges%' 
BEGIN
    -- Do whatever you want here...
END

GO
```